# MySQL PHP while loop - one record less than expected returned

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I have run into an interesting problem with retrieving data from mysql tables using one select query with couple of joins.

1) **query:**

```
$task_details = "SELECT tasks.task, ";
$task_details = $task_details . "tasks.description,";
$task_details = $task_details . "tasks.finishby, ";
$task_details = $task_details . "responsibles.full_name, ";
$task_details = $task_details . "task_assignments.completed, ";
$task_details = $task_details . "tasks.id, ";
$task_details = $task_details . "responsibles.user_id ";
$task_details = $task_details . "FROM tasks,task_assignments,responsibles ";
$task_details = $task_details . "WHERE ";
$task_details = $task_details . "tasks.id = task_assignments.id_task AND ";
$task_details = $task_details . "responsibles.id = task_assignments.id_assignee AND ";
$task_details = $task_details . "tasks.id = $id_task;";

$task_details_q = mysql_query($task_details) or die(mysql_error());
```

1a) **Resulting example query:**

```
SELECT tasks.task, tasks.description, tasks.finishby, responsibles.full_name, task_assignments.completed, tasks.id, responsibles.user_id
FROM tasks, task_assignments, responsibles
WHERE tasks.id = task_assignments.id_task
AND responsibles.id = task_assignments.id_assignee
AND tasks.id =19
```

2) **HTML / PHP code:**

```
<table class="task_table">
        <thead>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Due date</th>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
        </thead>
        <?php

        $even = false;
        $trow = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q))
        {

            $trow = $trow . "<tr";
             if($even) $trow = $trow . " style=\"background-color: #f2f2ed; \"";
            $trow = $trow. ">";
            $trow = $trow . "<td >$row[0]</td>";
            $trow = $trow . "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
            $trow = $trow . "<td>" . date('d-m-Y',$row[2]) . "</td>";
            $trow = $trow . "<td>$row[3]</td>";
            $trow = $trow . "<td style=\"text-align: center;\" >";
            if($row[4] > 0)
            {
                $trow = $trow . "<a href=\"javascript:modifyCompleted('remove','$row[6]',$row[5])\" title=\"Click to change completion of this task by this person\">yes</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                $trow = $trow . "<a href=\"javascript:modifyCompleted('add','$row[6]',$row[5])\" title=\"Click to change completion of this task by this person\">no</a>";
            }
            $trow = $trow . "</td>";
            $trow = $trow . "</tr>";

            $even =! $even;
            $number = $number + 1;
        }
            $trow = $trow . "<tr style=\"border-top: 1px solid #666666;\"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>";
            $trow = $trow . "<td>";
            $trow = $trow . "<a href=\"javascript:modifyCompleted('add_all','all',$task_details_array[5])\" title=\"Click to complete all\">Complete all</a>";
            echo $trow;
        ?>
    </table><br />
    <span style="text-align: center;display:block;font-size: 12px;"><a href="tasks.php">Go back to task overview</a></span>
```

3) **Problem / Question**: For some reason the displayed table always omits **one** record.I have used the same (or very similar concept) in number of PHP scripts but have never run into the same issue. I think the query itself is not a problem - when I run it directly against the DB, it returns correct number of values...(I think).

Comment: FYI, it is very likely that you are susceptible to SQL injection.  You should always escape data used in queries.  Better yet would be to learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problem, but you are not completing your last row. Do you see the correct results in the source code?

Comment: @jeroen: Good eyes and you're right - last row wasn't 'closed'. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.:(

Comment: @Brad: thanks for the input but data in the DB was already escaped during the data entry.

Comment: What record is missing, the first, the last, somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source? Maybe it is just not showing because of HTML errors. For instance, the last table row seems to lack closing TD and TR

Comment: @jeroen: it's the first record actually; I've added the 'order by' to be sure.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is between your mysql_query call and the start of your while loop.  Are you sure you don't call mysql_fetch_array somewhere before your loop starts?  Can you post the code leading up to what you've already posted?

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1) You should not be submitting an answer ever time you add info.  You should click "Edit" under your original question and add the new info into the question.

2) I think if I clarify how `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_array` work you'll see what's happening.

When you call `mysql_query` with a "SELECT", query it returns a `resource`.  This `resource` is just a reference to a record set.  Then when you call `mysql_fetch_array` on that `resource` it will return the current record from the set, and advance the record pointer.

So, when you first call `mysql_query` the record pointer points to the first result.  Then you call `mysql_fetch_array` the first record is returned as an array, and the pointer advances to the 2nd record.  The next time you call `mysql_fetch_array` this 2nd record is returned and the pointer will then point to the 3rd record.

If there is no 3rd record, the next time you call `mysql_fetch_array` it will not be able to find a corresponding record, and will return false.

This is why you use `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM))`.  You are putting a result into the variable `$row` and advancing the result pointer, then perfoming some actions with `$row`.  Eventually you will advance the pointer past the last result and `$row` will be false, which will stop your while loop from advancing.

Now that I've gone through the theory here's what's happening with your code (I'll just remove irrelevant code with `//...` and add my own comments along the way):

```
$task_details_q = mysql_query($task_details) or die(mysql_error());
//now you have a resource $task_details_q, it points to the first result


$task_details_array = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM);
//you retreive the first result, and advance the pointer to the second result

for($x=0;$x < sizeof($task_details_array);$x++)
{
            //you perform operations (echo'ing in this case) on your first result
    echo $x . ". : " . $task_details_array[$x] . "<br />";
}

//... HTML CODE SKIPPED

$even = false;
$trow = "";

//the first time this while statement is called you place the data from the second result in $row,
        //and advance the pointer to the third result
//the next time you go through the loop you try to place the data from the third result in $row,
        //since you say there are only 2 results to your query $row is simply false. 
        //This causes the while to stop executing and the code to continue on
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM))
{
    //... PRINT TABLE CELLS FROM $row SKIPPED
}

//... REMAINING HTML SKIPPED
```

I'm unsure if you actually need the block of code:

```
$task_details_array = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM);
for($x=0;$x < sizeof($task_details_array);$x++)
{
    echo $x . ". : " . $task_details_array[$x] . "<br />";
}
```

or if you just added it for debugging.  If it's just there for debugging, remove it and your first result will be displayed in the while loop.  If you need that `for` loop to execute, comment on this answer and I'll edit my answer to use the first result both in the `for` and `while` loops.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply - just noticed it. Anyway; yes - the FOR loop is there just for debugging. I understand what you meant - because the query result is put into an array once BEFORE the actual `while` loop, first time it's called within the `while` loop the pointer is already at the position [1] rather than [0]... I have moved the line `$task_details_array = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM);` below the `while` loop and it's worked like a charm! Big thanks and THUMBS UP!

Comment: @TomasH If I answered your question please accept my answer.  Also, it would be great if you cleaned up this question: take the extra info you put in as answers and edit them into the original question and delete the answers.

Answer (score 0):

As the php seems correct, it is possible that the cause of the problem is in the html. Your header row does not have `<tr>` tags so perhaps the browser is choking on that as you are missing the first record.

After fixing this, I would recommend to check your html in an html validator to make sure there are no more mistakes there.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben: This is the complete code between `mysql_query($task_details)` and `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q))`:

```
 $task_details_q = mysql_query($task_details) or die(mysql_error());
 $task_details_array = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM);

for($x=0;$x < sizeof($task_details_array);$x++)
{
    echo $x . ". : " . $task_details_array[$x] . "<br />";
}
```

?>

```
<h3>Task details - "<?php echo strtoupper($task_name);  ?>"</h3>
<span class="notifierOK">Table below lists all people assigned to the task - including the status (complete / incomplete). To change person's status click on the 'yes' or 'no' link. If you then go back
to (<a href="tasks.php">previous page</a>) the completion percentage value will be re-calculated.</span><br />

<form id="task_details" method="post" name="task_details" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;width: 800px;box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #888888;">
<table class="task_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Due date</th>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
            <tr />
        </thead>
        <?php

        $even = false;
        $trow = "";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($task_details_q,MYSQL_NUM))
```

Please note I have added the 'MYSQL_NUM' as array type based on your suggestion so it doesn't necessarily belong there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i had the same issue.

```
$run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $stores);

                if ($run_query === false){
                    //error
                }else if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query)){
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
                    echo 'bla bla bla' //on this echo I needed to show the data once.
                    $run_query =  null;
                    $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $stores);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) { //and here I needed to show up the loops of the results of my query.}
```

So... I just reset the variable that runned the query and re-runned the search. It worked for me! ;)